# How do I install my graphics driver for Dell Latitude D620?

Tags: installation, drivers, video

I have a Dell Latitude D620 with 11.10 on it, and I am wondering how to install Intel or Intel-Compatible drivers for my integrated video card.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to install the drivers are present in your kernel

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, Ubuntu supports most hardware out of the box.
You do not really need to install extra drivers.
If Unity and other features works as expected, you have the correct hardware configuration.

If your graphics card shows up as "Unknown" (what usually happens with on-board Intel cards, also happened with my GM45), open terminal, and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Or install it from here via the Software Center:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mesa-utils/